# Add Row to TableView from another UIView

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have a `UIViewController` with a save button. When I click it I add a string to an array that is in a `UITableViewController`. I have a segue that then goes to the table view and I want the new object in the array to display as a row in the table.

How can I get the data from the view controller to show up on the table view controller?

What I am doing isn't working.

UIViewController:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showFindTable"])
    {
        FindTableViewController *findTableVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        findTableVC.titles addObject:titleField.text];
        [findTableVC.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

UITableViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.titles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FindCell";
    FindTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.title.text = [self.titles objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Inside the table view controller I initialize the arrays. So when I add the object does it just revert back to an empty array when `viewDidLoad` is called? I plan on eventually persisting the data using Core Data. So I think that would solve it if this is the problem. Until then, how could I get it to work?

I tried to initialize the title array with one string. That string displays. So it does look like is it because I am re initializing the array every time the table view is loaded. Where do I/Should I initialize the array somewhere else?

Comment: Are you implementing the data source method: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section?

Answer (score 0):

In my project i used like this

Crete object for class where you want to add data to cell as follows.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WhatsNewCell";

WhatsNewCell *cell = (WhatsNewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
//if (nil == cell)
{
    cell = [[WhatsNewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
return cell;
}
```

but here WhatsNewCell is the subclass of **UITableViewCell**
and in that class create methods and add like

```
 - (void)createCellLabels
{    

albumNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, 5.0, 200.0, 50.0)];
albumNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
albumNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.14 green:0.29 blue:0.42 alpha:1]; 
albumNameLabel.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
albumNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:albumNameLabel];

artistNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, 28.0, 200.0, 50.0)];
artistNameLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
artistNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
artistNameLabel.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
artistNameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:artistNameLabel];

genresLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 0.0, 200.0, 25.0)];
genresLabel1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
genresLabel1.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.14 green:0.29 blue:0.42 alpha:1]; 
genresLabel1.font =  [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
genresLabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.contentView addSubview:genresLabel1];

}
```

may be its helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't think it quite matches my situation, though. I want to dynamically add to an array that will then be displayed in my table. But my table row count is always 0 so I'm not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegate:

ViewController.h (Declare delegate)

```
@protocol delegateName <NSObject>
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSString)strToAdd;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)save:(id)sender {
   [delegete prepareForSegue:titleField.text];
}
```

UITableViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(NSString)strToAdd {
  [self.title addObject:strToAdd];
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```